# Stream audio with websocket and get back audio transcription obtained with Google speech API

Tags: websocket, stream, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I have  a client which takes audio from mic then sends it to a remote server via websocket stream.

Server side I get the audio stream from websocket

```
const WebSocket = require('websocket-stream');
const wss = WebSocket.createServer({host: '192.168.254.161', port: 8090},handle);

function handle(stream)  {
  stream.pipe(recognizeStream); 
  stream.on('close', function (){
    console.log("stream closed")
  }).on('error', function() {
    console.log("stream error")
  })
}

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('%s bytes received', message.length);
        ws.send("some mesage")
  }).on('close', function () {
       ws.send("End of audio data")
  }).on('error',function (err) {
      console.log("error:",err)
  });
});
```

and send it to Google Speech API using SpeechClient with streamingRecognize

```
const recognizeStream = client
  .streamingRecognize(request)
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', (data) => {
    process.stdout.write(
      data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
        ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
        : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
    );
  });
```

All works and I get the transcript written to che server console..

Now I need to send the transcript back via websocket, but I cannot find how to do it. The only place where I can send something back is in the ws event handler, but here I do not have access to the transcript data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable from a callback function to another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398322/passing-a-variable-from-a-callback-function-to-another-function)

Answer (score 1):

You create the stream when connection is available and use the connection variable to send back the data:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('%s bytes received', message.length);
        ws.send("some mesage")
  }).on('close', function () {
       ws.send("End of audio data")
  }).on('error',function (err) {
      console.log("error:",err)
  });


  const recognizeStream = client
        .streamingRecognize(request)
        .on('error', console.error)
        .on('data', (data) => {

          // We send it back here, ws is still accessible

          ws.send(
                data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
              ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
              : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
          );
        });

});
```

There are different methods too - you can use global variable to pass a connection or wrap it within some prototype.